# Mock of store action of vuex does not mocked

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I have small vue component that on created hook dispatch some action

```
@Component
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  created() {
    store.dispatch('module/myAction', { root: true });
  }
}
```

and I wrote next test

```
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(VueRouter);
const localRouter = new VueRouter();
describe('SomeComponent.vue Test', () => {
  let store: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        module: {
          namespaced: true,
          actions: {
            myAction: jest.fn()
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  it('is component created', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(SomeComponent, {
      localVue,
      store,
      propsData: {}
    });

    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but for some reason the "real" code are executed and I got a warning

Answer (score 0):

*isVueInstance()* is deprecated. In your test you should mock *$store* object and it's *dispatch* function. I fixed typo in *created()*, here's my version of *SomeComponent* and working test, hope that would help.

```
@Component
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('module/myAction', { root: true })
  }
}

import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SomeComponent from '@/components/SomeComponent/SomeComponent.vue'

let wrapper: Wrapper<SomeComponent & { [key: string]: any }>

describe('SomeComponent.vue Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(SomeComponent, {
      mocks: {
        $store: {
          dispatch: jest.fn()
        }
      }
    })
  })
  it('is component created', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$store.dispatch).toBeCalled()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$store.dispatch).toBeCalledWith('module/myAction', { root: true })
  })
})
```

Also keep in mind that when you test *SomeComponent* or any other component you should not test store functionality, you should just test, that certain actions/mutations were called with certain arguments. The store should be tested separately. Therefore you don't need to create real *Vuex Store* when you test components, you just need to mock $*store* object.